# How to install ZendFramework 2 in windows 7 XAMPP?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, installation, xampp

There are many documentation about how to install Zend Framework 2. But they are hard to understand. I've tried lot of guidance in the web. But still I couldn't install ZF2.

This might be a duplicate question. But I went through most of them and ended up with no success.

Can any one please give me the simple step by step installation guidance?

I'm using XAMPP on windows 7

Thanks a lot

EDIT: I'm getting this error
[image]

Comment: you need to first download skeleton application from github. That would be easy to understand.

Comment: I tried with that also. But no luck :(

Comment: what problem you are facing now?

Comment: See the attached image

Comment: it's weird can you test http://www.wampserver.com/ in place of xamp ? And see if you have the same error ? I have and use zf2 on windows with wampserver and i never had those issues.

Comment: Do you have copy all the library files inside the 'vendor/ZF2/library' and set the zf2 path in `init_autoloader.php`.

Comment: Yes there's a library folder inside the project folder. But I didn't modify any code in `init_autoloader.php`. Instead I created the user variable as `ZF2_PATH`

Comment: i am saying in your `init_autolader.php` there is some code like `$zf2Path = false;

if (is_dir('vendor/ZF2/library')) {
    $zf2Path = 'vendor/ZF2/library';
} elseif (getenv('ZF2_PATH')) {      
    $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH');
} elseif (get_cfg_var('zf2_path')) { 
    $zf2Path = get_cfg_var('zf2_path');
}` so you have to set all the libraries in your project as you named `zf2` so it should be inside 'zf2/vendor/ZF2/library/', because the directory for library is set in your code is inside the `vendor/ZF2/library`

Comment: Thanks. I set the path as you mentioned. But now i'm getting this error `Fatal error: Can't inherit abstract function Zend\Validator\Translator\TranslatorInterface::translate() (previously declared abstract in Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface) in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\library\Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator.php on line 19`

Comment: which version of php and zf2 are you using?

Comment: ZF 2.3 require php 5.4 and above. make sure you are using higher version of php. this is an error with version 5.3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55125/discussion-between-prashu-and-sukeshini).

Comment: Thanks prashu. My php version is 5.3.8. I'll update it and re-try the steps.

Answer (score 3):

once you download skeleton application from [Github](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) you have run following command from command prompt

```
 cd ZendSkeletonApplication
 php composer.phar self-update
 php composer.phar install
```

make sure you have php version greater than 5.3.3

php command not run directly in command prompt if path variable is not set

to check path variable set or not type **php -v** if command not recognized than please set environmental variable.